# slideshow component - small bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to build a small slideshow component using jquery just for learning purposes (I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel).

The component is pretty simple:

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-controller prev">
    <p>prev</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/FF9800" alt="">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/757575" alt="">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/BDBDBD" alt="">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/2196F3" alt="">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/00BCD4" alt="">
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x200/009688" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-controller next">
    <p>next</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
  var prev = $('.prev');
  var next = $('.next');
  var img = $('.slideshow-wrapper img');

  var slides = 2;

  img.slice(slides).css({ 'display': 'none' });

  next.on('click', function() {
    img.css({ 'display': 'none' });
    img.slice(slides, slides + 2).css({ 'display': '' });

    slides += 2; 

    if (slides === 8) 
        { slides = 0; img.slice(slides, slides + 2).css({ 'display': '' }); }

    console.log('next');
    console.log(slides);
  });

  prev.on('click', function() {
    slides -= 2;
    if (slides === 0) { slides = 6; }

    img.css({ 'display': 'none' });
    img.slice(slides - 2, slides).css({ 'display': '' });

    console.log('previous');
    console.log(slides);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

I am able to detect if the last slide is reached, it goes back to slide index `0` (if user clicks on next). Or the other way around (if the user starts by clicking on "prev") reach slide 6.

THE PROBLEM:

Once it successfully reaches say (0 through 6) and it restarts, the first 2 slides show twice (you need to click twice in order to pass the first slide).

I used `console.log(slides)` in order to see the problem and it looks like it goes to 0 then 2. Obviously because I said go to slide 0 if the user reached slide index 5. I don't know how to solve that problem until now.

I'm pretty sure that it's something silly that I forgot to do.

Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/marco321/beah5v0d/

Thanks a lot! 
Mark

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my problem, I simply forgot to add another `if else` statement.

```
if (slides === 8) { 
  slides = 0; 
  img.slice(slides, slides + 2).css({ 'display': '' }); 
  if (slides === 0) { 
    slides = 2; img.slice(slides).css({ 'display': 'none' }); 
  }
}
```

Once I detect that slide is index 0, then I simply must reassign it to 2. Now, I'll be able to jump onto the second set of slides...